# Concurrent freehand drawing in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using fabric.js for a collaborative whiteboard project. I want freehand drawing paths to be drawn concurrently by several users. To do this I figured I could create a new `PencilBrush` for each remote user and simulate freehand drawing by calling the `onMouseDown()`, `onMouseMove()` and `onMouseUp()` methods of the PencilBrush class whenever the remote user performs those actions. I've created a jsfiddle that does something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/dkostro/7sx8N/21/

It draws two paths concurrently and the user can also draw on the canvas meanwhile. As you see one of the paths is never seen before `onMouseUp()` and freehand drawing it's not very pretty. I figured the problem was that each `PencilBrush` instance clears the upper canvas element before calling the `_render` function, thus only one of the paths can appear simultaneously.

Can you think of a way to make it work smoothly without having to mess up too much with fabric.js code? The one solution I thought of is having a separate canvas element for each `PencilBrush`, but that would be messing up with fabric.js code, and may not be a clean way to do it. Any other suggestions?

**EDIT**

I have implemented this one solution I have been thinking of in my question (separate canvas element for each user). http://jsfiddle.net/stropitek/DzygL/14/. I am not sure to what number of users this can scale to, or if this is a good solution, but in this example at least it seems to work well.